# Left align text that is flushed right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image: picture]

I want the row kandidatnivå, 15 hp to be aligned to left with examensarbete nr. xxx. How do I solve this?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \scriptsize
Institutionen för Fastigheter och Byggande\\
Civilingenjör Samhällsbyggnad\\
Fastighetsekonomi och fastighetsjuridik
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \scriptsize
\begin{flushright}
Examensarbete  nr. xxx\\
Kandidatnivå, 15 hp
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Wrap the text within `\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}...\end{tabular}`.  You also need a `\noindent` _before_ the first `minipage`.  Add `\usepacakge{showframe}` to see the effect.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Answer (score 2):

For a flushed view on *both* ends, you can use the following `tabular` specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\scriptsize%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  Institutionen för Fastigheter och Byggande \\
  Civilingenjör Samhällsbyggnad \\
  Fastighetsekonomi och fastighetsjuridik
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
  Examensarbete  nr. xxx \\
  Kandidatnivå, 15 hp
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

For a 50/50 split of the two boxes (one on the left half of the page and one on the right half), both with a left alignment, use the following `tabular` specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\scriptsize%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
  Institutionen för Fastigheter och Byggande \\
  Civilingenjör Samhällsbyggnad \\
  Fastighetsekonomi och fastighetsjuridik
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
  Examensarbete  nr. xxx \\
  Kandidatnivå, 15 hp
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

Of course, other alignments are also possible, depending on your setup.

Answer (score 2):

For such things, defining a command is better, as it allows for easier input. It also allows for easily changing the output format. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the page frame

\newcommand{\topinfo}[2]{%
  \begingroup\scriptsize\noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #2
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular*}\par\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\topinfo{
  Institutionen för Fastigheter och Byggande\\
  Civilingenjör Samhällsbyggnad\\
  Fastighetsekonomi och fastighetsjuridik
}{
  Examensarbete  nr. xxx\\
  Kandidatnivå, 15 hp
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you like to change the fontsize, you'd need to modify just the definition, leaving the input in `\topinfo` exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Two left-aligned `\Longunderstacks` can achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\scriptsize%
\Longunderstack[l]{
  Institutionen för Fastigheter och Byggande \\
  Civilingenjör Samhällsbyggnad \\
  Fastighetsekonomi och fastighetsjuridik
}
\hfill
\Longunderstack[l]{
  Examensarbete  nr. xxx \\
  Kandidatnivå, 15 hp
}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]